# Chrome freezes and give me XHR finished loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I fetch new data via ajax every x seconds and replace the content on the page. It works pretty well, but if I switch app or tab in chrome and go back again the page freezes every time it loads the data, seemingly random. If I refresh the page it acts normal again, until I go away for a while and go back to the browser tab. This is what Chrome writes in the console: "XHR finished loading". I think it's only happening in Chrome. Ideas? This is my code:

```
function refreshContent() {
    if( $('#edit-col').length == 0 )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "content.php",
            dataType: 'text',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {    
                var contentArr = ["#container", "#progress-container", "#project-progress"];
                var arrayLength = contentArr.length;
                for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
                    var el = $(data).find(contentArr[i]);
                    if( $(contentArr[i]).html() != el.html() )
                    {
                        $(contentArr[i]).replaceWith(el);
                    }
                }       
            }
        });
    }
}

var starttime = 5000;
var time = starttime;
var maxtime = 320000;
var idleInterval;
$(document).ready(function () {

    idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);

    $(this).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        clearInterval(idleInterval);
        idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
    });
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        clearInterval(idleInterval);
        idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
    });
    $(this).on('keypress', function (e) {
        clearInterval(idleInterval);
        idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {

    console.log('refreshContent is called after '+time+' milliseconds');
    refreshContent();

    time *= 2;
    if( time > maxtime ) { time = maxtime; }
    clearInterval(idleInterval);
    idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, time);
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Did you paste it correctly?

Comment: @Terry Thanks, working now?

Comment: Freeze how? The window freezes, or just no new content? Also doing `$(data)` is going to recreate the jQuery object, and all the html elements that `data` represents, in each iteration of the loop. If it is a lot of html it could be a performance issue. You should save it to a variable and use that variable in the loop

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yeah, I can't click on anything for a couple of seconds. Almost like it's not synchronous. Hovers stop working, links, scrolling of the page etc. Do you have an example of how the variable solution could look like? Maybe it helps. Thanks

Comment: Like `$data = $(data);` right before the loop, and then inside it `$data.find(...)`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks, I changed! Give me a couple of mins and I'll see if it helped. It's very random and only happens when I leave the window and go back so I can't re-create it 100% of the times. Please let me know if you see any other perfomance issues in the code. Thx!

Comment: @PatrickEvans Actually looks like it's running better now! I'll monitor and test a little more. Maybe it was that simple.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I haven't seen the problem again since I changed the code. I think we can call it solved! Thanks again!